# JFormattedTextField set value and text null after inputting wrong format

Tags: java, swing, date, format, jformattedtextfield

I'm working with Java Application with JFormattedTextField. I have some problems that:

1. How to set JFormattedTextField with can accept "/" and "-"
2. I want to set jformattedtextfield value and text to null or "" after entering wrong format.

Example:

2.1.JFormattedTextField ftf .... with format ("yyyy-MM-dd")

[image]

2.2. Input right format: 1990-5-6

[image]

2.3. Leave ftf

[image]

2.4. Then focus ftf and input wrong format: 5-6-1990

[image]

2.5. Leave ftf then it recognize wrong format but return something else

[image]

But what I want is that I must be null or empty.

[image]

How can I do it?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: +1 nice question, yes is possible to reset, search in my posts tagged by jformattedtextfield

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on this forum and I hope I don't mess up. For the first question, you can use MaskFormatter. This will also ensure that the value is never entered wrong.

```
new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("####-##-##"));



private static MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s) {
    MaskFormatter formatter = null;
    try {
        formatter = new MaskFormatter(s);
        formatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
    } catch (java.text.ParseException exc) {
        System.err.println("formatter is bad: " + exc.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    return formatter;
}
```